# syntax for Junaio / AREL XML schema

Tags: augmented-reality, junaio

I am fairly new to augmented reality implementations, and have been handed down a project which used Junaio sometime back in 2012. I need to re-implement everything from scratch, and I think I've been fairly successful so far; I can get my POI's to show up on a map and in the list, however the 3D Models for those points and thumbnail/icon images for those POIs do not show up in the app when I load my channel. Here is an example of the XML being used for one of the POIs. Is there something I'm missing?

```
<object id="3">
<title>
<![CDATA[ Post Office by Esri ]]>
</title>
<thumbnail>
<![CDATA[
<path_to_image>/USPS_logo.jpg
]]>
</thumbnail>
<icon>
<![CDATA[
<path_to_image>/USPS_logo.jpg
]]>
</icon>
<location>
<lat>34.057962</lat>
<lon>-117.194614</lon>
<alt>0</alt>
</location>
<popup>
<description>
<![CDATA[ USPS ]]>
</description>
<buttons>
<button id="url" name="Website">
<![CDATA[ http://www.usps.com/ ]]>
</button>
</buttons>
</popup>
<assets3d>
<model>
<![CDATA[
<path_to_model_zip>/Redlands_NewYorkSt_PO.zip
]]>
</model>
<transform>
<translation>
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<z>0</z>
</translation>
<rotation type="eulerdeg">
<x>0</x>
<y>0</y>
<z>0</z>
</rotation>
<scale>
<x>1000</x>
<y>1000</y>
<z>1000</z>
</scale>
</transform>
</assets3d>
</object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to find support for that is on metaio helpdesk. maybe this helps:
http://helpdesk.metaio.com/questions/17632/gps-tracking-scale-over-distance